# Serverless keeps trying to create user pool domain when it already exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have a aws cognito user group configured to my serverless.yml. Whenever I do a serverless deploy, it will try to create the same user pool domain even though it already exist, hence returning me the error of:

```
[aws-cognito-idp-userpool] domain already exist
```

The only workaround is for me to delete the user pool domain every time I want to do a serverless deploy from the AWS UI. Anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no way to skip it,
**Check this -** https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183

You can try to break the serverless.yaml file into multiple files and deploy them separately for easier management,
So use the file only to create/deploy resources you need to freshly create.

The serverless.yaml will get converted into the vendor-specific Code to Infra service file,
eg. CloudFormation for AWS

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a CloudFormation issue vs. a Serverless issue. I ran into it in my Serverless app, **BUT** had my *UserPool** resources independently defined in the `resources` section of the serverless.yml file. I changed the `Domain Prefix` and that requires the resource to be recreated. Here's the issue: CloudFormation always creates a resource first before deleting the old one, which blocks the new domain from being associated with the User Pool.

I've seen this behavior with other resources and the recommended behavior is to:

```
 1. Blank out the resource from the template
 2. Update the stack (deletes resource)
 3. Restore the resource in template
 4. Update the stack (creates a new one vs. replace).
```

This way you still leverage your automation tools without going to the console. Not perfect, and it'd be more preferable if there was a way to force the replacement sequence in CloudFormation. If your setup has Serverless generating the resource, then deleting via the console may be your only option.